refreshApex method partially updates the UI when there is realtime values in the database
I have been struggling to find the cause for this for the past two days.
I have a LWC component that reverts the changes made to the workorder line items. After reverting and saving it to the database, I send a message using LMS to another component to update the UI using refreshApex. The issue I am seeing is some fields of the line item dont get updated to the latest data. I did console log on the data and I do see the right values in there.
Here in the snip below. The quantity value has been updated from 3 to 2 and the text color is based of a picklist field value called change type which has blue when the value is Amended, green when the value is created and black when the value is none.
Just to make it more clear-
Picklist Field -
Change_Type__c

Amended - the text color will be blue
Created - the text color will be green
None -- the text color will be black


After the LMS message is received the line item should revert the changes from 2 to 3 and the color of the text should be updated to black. The result I get is the color of the text is updated to black which means the value for the change type is updated but the quantity field is getting updated intermittently.
After update snip. The Quantity field is not reverted.

Here is the code for the component that receives the LMS message -
@track records = [];//The wire method will load the records into this variable
@track wiredRecords;//Temporary variable to store the wired data and refresh the 
 datatable after a record is updated or created

@wire(MessageContext)
messageContext;

connectedCallback() {
    this.subscription = subscribe(
        this.messageContext,
        WorkOrderLineItemsUpdateMessageChannel,
        (message) => {
            console.log('Message Received:', JSON.stringify(message));
            if (this.wiredRecords) {
                return refreshApex(this.wiredRecords)
                    .then(() => {
                        console.log('Apex data refreshed');
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error('Error refreshing Apex:', error);
                    });
            }
        }
    );
}

@wire(getWorkOrderLineItems, { workOrderId: '$recordId' })
    wiredWorkOrderLineItems(result) {
        console.log('Wired Method Called');

    if (result.data) {
        console.log('Inside If')
        //The wiredRecords variable is used to refresh the data in the datatable after a record is updated or created
        this.wiredRecords = result;
        //Load the parts to search based on the filter set in the below method 
        this.loadPartPickerFiltersOnModal(result.data);
        //This is done mainly to get the part name from the related part record. Without this it will return only the Id of the related part record
        let flattenedRecords = result.data.map(record => {
            let flattenedRecord = { ...record };
            flattenedRecord.partName = record.Part_Name__r ? record.Part_Name__r.Name : '';

            switch (record.Change_Type__c) {
                case 'Created':
                    flattenedRecord.rowColor = 'datatable-green-text-color';
                    flattenedRecord.iconName = 'utility:new';
                    flattenedRecord.buttonIconName = 'action:delete';
                    flattenedRecord.isDeleteDisabled = false;
                    break;
                case 'Amended':
                    if (record.Item_Quantity__c == 0) {
                        flattenedRecord.rowColor = 'slds-text-color_error';
                        flattenedRecord.iconName = 'utility:delete';
                    } else {
                        flattenedRecord.rowColor = 'datatable-blue-text-color';
                        flattenedRecord.iconName = 'utility:edit';
                    }
                    flattenedRecord.buttonIconName = '';
                    flattenedRecord.isDeleteDisabled = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    flattenedRecord.rowColor = 'slds-text-color_default';
                    flattenedRecord.buttonIconName = '';
                    flattenedRecord.isDeleteDisabled = true;
                    break;
            }
            return flattenedRecord;
        });

        //this.records = flattenedRecords;
        this.records = [...flattenedRecords];
        this.workOrderLineItemsCount = 'Work Order Line Items (' + this.records.length + ')';
    } else {
        this.showToast('Error', 'Error Loading Parts', 'destructive-text');
    }
}

I do see all the console log statements getting printed.
Anybody with expertise in this please help.

The clue here is the cell's background color. It appears that the user performed an inline edit, and then used a non-standard method to save this data to the database. In that case, the draftValues property hasn't been reset correctly, and so it wants to retain the 2 that was edited into the field. Add the following line of code into the wire handler to clear these draft values:
this.refs.datatable.draftValues = [];

And to reference your table, add a lwc:ref:
<lightning-datatable lwc:ref="datatable" ...


Thanks @sfdcfox. you are right and your code worked.
